# How do I import data into Craft?

Tags: import, migration

What's the best known way to import masses of data into Craft?

Are there tools that support the migration of content/users from say XML, JSON etc.

Comment: While this other question is framed around Wordpress, the answers apply to broader data import options and may be relevant here: http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/136/115

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is craftimport which is an 'unsupported' starting point for importing entries from an XML source.

https://github.com/clearbold/craftimport

There is also Import:

https://github.com/boboldehampsink/import

which can import from CSV sources.

Check out http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins for a list of current Craft plugins.

Answer (score 15):

If you’re comfortable with PHP, Craft has some plugin APIs that make creating content relatively painless. For example, [EntriesService::saveEntry()](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EntriesService#saveEntry-detail).

Answer (score 11):

As far as ExpressionEngine goes, it looks like Mark Reeves has cooked up a [starter plugin](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/ee-craft-import) for that purpose.

Bob Olde Hampsink made an [import plugin](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/import) as well that works with CSV's.

Comment: And there is always the option to write a importing plugin for your specific site's needs using Craft's services.

Answer (score 5):

It's not mentioned above, but in my experience the [FeedMe](https://github.com/verbb/feed-me) plugin is by far the best way to import content.